# Excel wouldn't import Access query that contains VBA calls

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

Access and Excel 2013

Trying to use an Access base as a data source in Excel, it seems like if a query calls a VBA function, Excel doesn't see it.

This query shows up in Excel:

```
SELECT "StaticValue" AS static_value;
```

This one doesn't:

```
SELECT my_function() AS value_from_vba;
```

The code of the module containing my_function being:

```
Option Compare Database

Function my_function() As String
    my_function = "ValueFromVBA"
End Function
```

How can I call a VBA function in an Access query and link this query to Excel ?

Comment: You can't. You'd have to automate access, run a make table query and then query that table in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm perhaps;
Make table and query the table (as stated in comments)

My preferred is just to export the data from access into a new worksheet that you need in excel, then you can do what you want with it if you are only getting values. Then you can go back in and update anything after (in your access tables) with VBA should you need it

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a table (SELECT … INTO …) that I refresh on a regular basis. This table is linkable within Excel. It is probably a dirty trick, but it does the job.